# If $A\in\Bbb \{\pm1,0\}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric of rank $<n$, does $A-I$ have rank $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, diagonalization, matrix-rank

Supposing we have a symmetric matrix $A\in\Bbb \{\pm1,0\}^{n\times n}$ of rank $m<n$ with all $+1$ or all $-1$ or all $0$ as diagonals and no $0$ on non-diagonals, when do we have $A-I$ to be full rank?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by $A\in\{\pm1\}^{n\times n}$?

Comment: I guess it means that all elements should be $1$ or $-1$, but then "-1 or 0 as diagonals" is slightly confusing, since 0 wouldn't be allowed anyway.

Comment: @Calle corrected

Comment: @egreg Calle is correct in interpretation